# Can we Join YouTube chrome-cast session from android sender app?

Tags: android, chromecast

I am new to Chrome-Cast, I'm trying to join my application to the YouTube session so that my  sender app will checks what is running on the chrome-cast by using the metadata returned on joinApplication().

I have been googling for information about how to join these sessions for some time, but cannot find anything helpful.

Please share any helpful information.

Thanks in advance.